# IPv6 autoconfig isn't working on 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, ipv6

I have several computers with various operating systems on my LAN, and one of them with Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, is the only box that can't autoconfigure itself an IPv6 address. rdisc6 times out on it, whereas it succeeds on all my other Linux boxes. What's up?

On the box on which ipv6 doesn't work, it has a Realtek 8187B wifi card:

```
[18:50:19] domitille:~
alisonc $ rdisc6 wlan1
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlan1...
Timed out.
Timed out.
Timed out.
No response.
```

On my Raspberry Pi with raspbian:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ rdisc6 eth0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on eth0...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :           No
Stateful other conf.      :          Yes
Router preference         :       medium
Router lifetime           :           30 (0x0000001e) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : 2001:470:xxxx::/64
  Valid time              :        86400 (0x00015180) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14400 (0x00003840) seconds
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8888
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8844
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:470:20::2
  DNS servers lifetime    :           10 (0x0000000a) seconds
 MTU                      :         1480 bytes (valid)
 Source link-layer address: 10:BF:48:xx:xx:xx
 from fe80::12bf:48ff:fexx:xxxx
```

On an old laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit, Atheros AR5212 wifi card:

```
owner@owner-ThinkPad-X60:~$ rdisc6 wlan0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlan0...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :           No
Stateful other conf.      :          Yes
Router preference         :       medium
Router lifetime           :           30 (0x0000001e) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : 2001:470:xxxx::/64
  Valid time              :        86400 (0x00015180) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14400 (0x00003840) seconds
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8888
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8844
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:470:20::2
  DNS servers lifetime    :           10 (0x0000000a) seconds
 MTU                      :         1480 bytes (valid)
 Source link-layer address: 10:BF:48:xx:xx:xx
 from fe80::12bf:48ff:fexx:xxxx
```

I'm using an Asus RT-N16 as my IPv6 router, with a tunnel by Hurricane Electric. The WLAN connected computers are connected to a Netgear WNDR3700v3 configured as a wireless AP.

Any pointers as to what to look for in the configuration on domitille would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed the IPv6 problem by upgrading to a 802.11n usb wireless card, the Asus USB-N10. Now it goes like this:

```
[00:06:40] domitille:~
alisonc $ rdisc6 wlan2
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlan2...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :           No
Stateful other conf.      :          Yes
Router preference         :       medium
Router lifetime           :           30 (0x0000001e) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : 2001:470:xxxx::/64
  Valid time              :        86400 (0x00015180) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14400 (0x00003840) seconds
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8888
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:4860:4860::8844
 Recursive DNS server     : 2001:470:20::2
  DNS servers lifetime    :           10 (0x0000000a) seconds
 MTU                      :         1480 bytes (valid)
 Source link-layer address: 10:BF:48:xx:xx:xx
 from fe80::12bf:48ff:fexx:xxxx
[00:06:47] domitille:~
alisonc $ lsusb | grep -i net
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N10 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
```

It's weird to me how switching wireless cards from one 802.11g to an 802.11n could have fixed the problem, but it did.